# Vertical centering multirow and row coloring in a table

Tags: tables, color, multirow, adjustbox

I am having issues working with multirow in my table, I cannot figure out how to center a vertical row and how to color all the cells related to it.

I am trying to create this table:

[image: Table and its problems]

This is the code that I am using to create the table above:

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}
\caption{Just a nice table}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|M{2.0cm}|}{name A} & name B & name C & name D & name E & name F\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A1}}} & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A2}}}\cellcolor{blue!25} & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}
```

Probably I am messing it up using `\arraystretch` regarding the centering problem, but I need to use it because the "Classification" name would go out of the table. Is there a different way to handle it?

The color problem I don't know if there is a function to deal with multiple rows without painting over the written part.

Another problem when I use the multirow is that a white or "ghost" row appears between the colored rows. As you can see below:

[image]

Any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first `\multirow` should cover 3 rows instead of 2.
2. You must color both cells that the second `\multirow covers. But then you should put the` \multirow`in the last row with a negative count to prevent the color overwriting the text (see the`multirow` documentation).
3. You might also have a look at the `tabular` package which is more powerful for complicated tables (although I wouldn't classify this one as complicated).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Just a nice table}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|M{2.0cm}|}{name A} & name B & name C & name D & name E & name F\\
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A1}}} & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!25} & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2mm}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A2}}}\cellcolor{blue!25}& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The first argument of `\multirow` is for standard (one-lined) rows, so you have to determine, by trial & error the number of equivalent standard rows. Note this number is not necessarily an integer.

For the coloured \multirow, you have to use `\cellcolor{…}` also in the empty cells  covered by the multirow.

Ol also simplified a bit your code; using `\parbox` is not necessary for the rotated boxes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\caption{Just a nice table}
\begin{center}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5.5}
\begin{tabular}{|c|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|M{2.0cm}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|M{2.0cm}|}{name A} & name B & name C & name D & name E & name F\\
\hline
\multirow{3.1}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A1}} & B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\cellcolor{blue!25}& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\cline{2-7}
\multirow{-2}{*}{\cellcolor{blue!25} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Classification A2}}& B & C & D & E & F & G\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\label{tab:multicol}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Just one question regarding the color. When I zoom in on the blue area of the table, there is a white (ghost) row dividing the multirow (between the 2 Bs). This white row crosses the 'a' of "Classification A2". I've added a print in the question, to better understand the problem. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: Are you using Acrobat Reader to view the PDF? I have heard that this is an artefact of how PDF viewers do the rounding of pixels and that Acrobat Reader is the only one that does it correctly.

Comment: I am using Overleaf to write my article. I am not sure which PDF reader it uses. The only way to "solve" this problem, is using the `nicematrix` package, but if there is a way to solve this without an extra package I guess it would be better...

Comment: @Codewraith If you want to solve this w/o a package, then you may consider using fewer horizontal and vertical lines.

Comment: @Codewraith; here is a solution using `\hhline` in the place of `\cline{2-7}` . Try using the code `\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue!25}]->{\arrayrulecolor{black}|------|}` (don't forget to  load the `hhline` package). This  makes a rule throughout the table, with the part in the first column of the same colour as the background.

Comment: @Bernard I tried your method but it didn't work, I also tried to change the ']' that you used to a '}', but it also didn't work. I used the following code: `\hhline{|>{\arrayrulecolor{blue!50}}->{\arrayrulecolor{black}}|------|}`, but now I have two white lines :(

Comment: @Codewraith: I've checked. Indeed there remains a very thin padding of the `\hhline` , which remains uncoloured. Your white lines are to the `]`, which results from a mistyping. Anyway, there is a simple solution without `hhline`: replace `\cline{2-7}` with `\noalign{\vskip 0.2pt} \cline{2-7}`. On my pdfviewer, there's no white thin line in the first column.

Comment: @Bernard I've tried your solution out, but it increased the size of the white space, so I inverted the value and increased it so even with lesser or more zoom than usual I couldn't see the white rows. I've used `\noalign{\vskip -1pt} \cline{2-7}` for all the rows, and now I cannot perceive the white row. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Codewraith: I'm sorry, I mistyped, forgetting the `–`, and forgot to check what I wrote. Actually, in my LaTeX editor, I used $`vskip –0.2pt`.

Comment: @Bernard, no problem, it helped a lot :)